# i can add a data and i can only see through phpmyadmin.

Tags: php, html, css

here is the front end of it.
and this is the back end
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/#PMAURL-6:sql.php?db=bims&table=personal_info&server=1&target=&token=8254c6ededd52ca5284d30cf084621b9

Comment: Do you realize that no one can open this link except you?

Answer (score 2):

This question is wrongly asked. 
you may:

1. **Take screen shots**
2. **Be specific on where the problem is**
3. **And if you wish to provide link, make sure it is hosted** *not recommended at all for datab*ase
4. **And if it is a database, be careful not to share a sensitive database, Only share something that is strictly demo**